# Four Letter Word

Tags: word

What's a four letter word that sounds exactly the same if you take away the first and last letters?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Generally, the title should be short and the main puzzle text should be in the body.

Answer (score 30):

The answer is

> Know - >no

${} {} {} {} $

Answer (score 16):

How about:

> ENVY

When you take away the first and last letters, you're left with

> NV, which you would pronounce by the individual letters.

Answer (score 9):

> KNEE and NE

are both pronounced

> N IY1

according to the [CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict).